# Load data from helpers before ng-class renders

Tags: angularjs, meteor, ng-class, angular-meteor, checklist-model

I'm working on a project using Meteor and AngularJs.

I retrieve some data using helpers, and then I used ng-repeat to show them.

I'm using checklist-model (http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/) to get the list of the checkbox choices.

```
<li ng-repeat="t in types">
  <div ng-class="nametagClass(t)">{{t.name}}</div>
  <input type="checkbox" data-checklist-value="t" 
         data-checklist-model="chosenTypes" class="sub-checkbox" />
</li>
```

here is the ng-class function:

```
$scope.nametagClass=function(type){
            if($scope.chosenTypes.indexOf(type)>-1){
                return "nametag active-nametag";
            }

            return "nametag";
        }
```

The problem is, when the ng-class calls the function, the data from chosenTypes aren't loaded yet, so the checked elements don't get the "active-nametag" class. (However, when the data loads and check an element, the class changes just fine)

How can I delay the ng-class function call after the data loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `ng-if` in outer element like this

```
<li ng-if="types" ng-repeat="t in types">
  <div ng-class="nametagClass(t)">{{t.name}}</div>
  <input type="checkbox" data-checklist-value="t" data-checklist-model="chosenTypes" class="sub-checkbox" />
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ngIf` would be an option. I think that you can also use [`ngCloak`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak):

> The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template
>   from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled)
>   form while your application is loading.